# GraphQL query filter by current timestamp

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphcool

I'm wondering what would be a nice solution to **filter GraphQL queries by the current timestamp**, e.g:

```
query {
  appointments(createdAt: today) { }
}
```

or

```
query {
  appointments(createdAt_gte: now) { }
}
```

Is it recommended to create my own resolver functions here? How would they look like, when e.g. graph.cool is used as a backend?

I don't want to rely on the correct time of the client but use the server time instead.

Comment: I would say: Use a service, get the server time and write your own resolver to compare the date.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rely on the client side for the date, you can send a paramater on your query i.e.

```
query {
  appointments(latestsOnly: true) { }
}
```

and resolve that paramater to the current date in the backend